# How to set $PATH in PHP?

Tags: php, environment-variables

I am currently working on my own little project, but I have a little problem: I want to set the $PATH environment variable to `./bin`, so that when I use `exec()` and similar functions, it would only search for binary files in that directory (unless I explicitly tell it otherwise).

I have already tried `putenv()`, which won't work unless I have safe-mode enabled, which I'd prefer not to; and I also tried `apache_setenv()`, but that didn't seem to work either.

Are there any other solutions I might want to try?

(I am using a Linux machine with PHP 5.3.2)

Comment: Did you mean "unless I have safe-mode disabled" ?

Comment: @greg0ire, no, it actually won't work unless I have safe-mode enabled. See for yourself on the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

Comment: "These directives have only effect when safe-mode itself is enabled!" from http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php. which is silly.

Comment: @sreservoir, exactly, and what's even worse is that safe-mode itself is deprecated....

Comment: yes, I read this, and I thought "directives" meant safe_mode_protected_env_vars, safe_mode_allowed_env_vars. But if you have tried...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to set it only in specific circumstances, you can do:

```
exec("PATH=/my/path ./bin");
```

Comment: Thanks, why didn't I think of that? :P

Comment: that PATH setting is kind of pointless since you're also giving an actual relative path.

Comment: @sreservoir No it's not. The path doesn't affect only the resolution of `./bin` (in this case it doesn't affect it at all, since it's a relative path). If `./bin` is e.g. a script that calls other applications it can affect the path resolution for them.

Answer (score 4):

The way to alter the PATH used by apache on Mac OS X is described here:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2008/Sep/msg00433.html

As stated in that post:

> [A]dd the following text into [the file
>   `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`] at the fifth
>   line:
>
> ```
> <key>EnvironmentVariables</key> 
> <dict>
> <key>PATH</key>
> <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin</ string>
> </dict>
> ```
>
> See the man page for `launchd.plist(5)` for details on the syntax I'm
>   using here.
>
> If you need to run your PHP commands as CLI sessions, you'll also
>   probably need to add `/opt/local/bin` as a new path under `/etc/paths.d`
>   work. For instance, something like this:
>
> ```
> shell> sudo echo "/opt/local/bin" >> /etc/paths.d/macports
> ```
>
> See the man page for `path_helper(8)`.

Answer (score 2):

instead of setting the path to `bin` and calling `foo`, why don't you just explicitly invoke `bin/foo`?

Answer (score 0):

If You have path set for Yours user AND if Your scripts run as Yours user, only thing You should do, is to set up this path for Yours shell, but is Your's scripts run as ie. apache user (www-data in debian-like systems) for this to work, You should set this PATH for that user explicte

Comment: The problem is that I do not want it to apply everywhere on the server, only in **one** PHP script...

Comment: Than, You cannot do that without disabling safe-mode (as my knowledge says, but i may be wrong), PATH is a shell-oriented environment variable, not a script-oriented