# Is it possible to temporarily change PATH in PHP?

Tags: php, windows, path

I tried using the following code to temporarily change `PATH` before using `exec()`.

```
$s1 = getenv ('PATH');
putenv('PATH=c:\bins');
$s2 = getenv ('PATH');
putenv('PATH='.$s1);
$s3 = getenv ('PATH');
var_dump($s1);
var_dump($s2);
var_dump($s3);
```

The first time the script runs everything works as expected.  Here's the output:

```
string 'C:\Program Files (x86)\'... (length=1400)
string 'c:\bins' (length=7)
string 'C:\Program Files (x86)\'... (length=1400)
```

However, it appears that PHP destroys `PATH` after this script runs because running it a second time produces the following output.

```
boolean false
string 'c:\bins' (length=7)
string '' (length=0)
```

I'm getting this behaviour on Windows with lighttpd and PHP 5.3 via fastcgi.  I haven't test with Linux/Apache yet.

The following approach doesn't work on windows (even if you use &):
[How to set $PATH in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550449/how-to-set-path-in-php)

Does anyone know a OS agnostic way to change `PATH`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `putenv('PATH=/www/uploads/path/to/evil/')`?;

Comment: I have a function that uses exec().  I want to make it fail in a unit test.

Comment: You want the path variable to persist after your script terminates?

Comment: @SalmanA, I don't want PATH to persist, that's why I set it back to its original value.  The problem is, after running the script once, PATH is not available to any scripts.  I have to restart the server to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for set_include_path http://www.php.net/set_include_path

```
<?php
//Set a new path
set_include_path('/usr/lib/pear');

// Works in all PHP versions
ini_set('include_path', '/usr/lib/pear');

//Add a new path to the already existing path throug get_include_path()
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
?>
```

Comment: No, I want PATH used by the OS for finding executables. This is used by php for finding php files.   http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path